# opencv python Add gridlines in Table where there is a gap

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

[image]

I would like to add gridlines in a table. The data is arranged such that I need to find the midpoint between the columns. I have illustrated the problem in the attached file where the image has already been manipulated. It is the red lines that I am wishing to overlay anywhere there is a gap between the columns. Any hints would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a rectangle to slide over the image and find the sums of white/black pixels.
After crossing a certain threshold of white/black pixels you can save the current x position.

[image: Sliding rectangle]

From there you can check where the values changed from True to False. You could use those x positions to find the those lines that you need.